# How to simply compare if current date is a holiday

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to compare the current date, using DateTime.Now, to a hard-coded list of select holidays to test whether or not the current date is equal to a holiday. I am just getting started with c# so I am not looking for an elegant answer, I am just trying to work with what I have to understand the outcomes.

```
 <script Language="c#" runat="server">
  void Page_Load()
  {
   DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
   dateToday.Text = " " + date.ToString("d");

   string newYear = "01/01/2016";
   if (newYear == dateTime.Now){
       message.Text = ("This is New Years");
       }
   }
  <body>
  <asp:label id="message" runat="server"/>
  </body>
```

Comment: hint: strings are not dates....(and vice versa)

Comment: Are you not allowed to compare a string to a string date? I thought converting the DateTime.Now to a string would allow me to compare it to another (string) date?

Comment: time portion.....

Comment: A good library for check is a date a public holiday is [Nager.Date](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.Date)

Example: DateSystem.IsPublicHoliday(date, CountryCode.US);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [`DateTime.Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date) to compare dates, here's an example

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime newYear = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
// or DateTime newYear = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2016");

if (newYear.Date == now.Date){
  message.Text = "This is new years";
}
```

You are better off using the `DateTime` structure when dealing with dates, as it conveys more meaning than a string. You also get more flexibility around sorting, filtering, manipulating and displaying the data when you want to do more complex operations. e.g.:

```
var holidays = new List<DateTime> { new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), new DateTime(2016, 12, 25) };
var now = DateTime.Now;

if (holidays.contains(now.Date){
  message.Text = "Today is a holiday!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare dates using strings.  There are too many different ways to represent dates to reliably compare them as strings.  Compare them as dates (and use `Today` instead of `Now` to ignore the time portion):

```
DateTime newYear = new DateTime(2016,1,1);
if (newYear == DateTime.Today)
```

Comment: Are you generally not able to compare two strings in c#, or is it just a best practice to compare the two items as they are?

Comment: @penmas you are not comparing 2 strings. You are comparing a string with a date

Comment: You can compare two _strings_ but it's a _literal_ comparison.  "01/01/2016" and "2016-01-01" are the same _date_ but different _strings_.

Comment: @penmas parse the string into a date object first

Comment: @deviantxdes Why parse a literal string?  Just create a `DateTime` in the first place.

Comment: @DStanley yes, obviously it isnt the best way to parse a literal string and then compare. I was just providing an option to OP to compare his current string with a date.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string into a date `DateTime.Parse()` and compare it.

```
if (DateTime.Parse(newYear)== DateTime.Now.Date)
```